# kendoui scheduler get resource by position

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to support drag drop to kendoui scheduler from external draggable object.

Using scheduler.view().content.kendoDropTargetArea I manage to support drop and given the offset I can get the timeSlot (scheduler.slotByPosition) which includes start and end.

The problem is that I am using multi-resources and want to get the resource for that slot/offset.

Is there any way to get a resource by position?

Answer (score 1):

This works perfect for me.

```
var resource = scheduler.resourcesBySlot(slot);
```